# Iterate extend to save calculate data from for loop (python)

Tags: python

I am trying to use extend to save data calculated from loop iterations. However, I get the error `'numpy.int64' object is not iterable`

```
x_hat1= commpy.channels.bsc(x[1],0.2)
Distance = []
for i in range(1, 6):
    Distance.extend(hamming_distance(x_hat1,x[i]))
```

So, I tried adding the loop inside the extend itself as follows

```
Distance.extend(value for i in range(1, 6), hamming_distance(x_hat1,x[i]))
```

But I get the error `Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument`. I checked the parenthesis a couple of times and they are correct. So, I don't know what is wrong.

Briefly, I want to find the hamming distances between one vector and several ones, and save it in the list "Distance" to use it later on.

Thanks

Comment: Does `hamming_distance` return one item or a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is `extend` expects a `list` as an argument. If you want to use a normal for loop, either make a single element list:

```
x_hat1= commpy.channels.bsc(x[1],0.2)
Distance = []
for i in range(1, 6):
    Distance.extend([hamming_distance(x_hat1,x[i])])
```

or use `append` instead of extend: `Distance.append(hamming_distance(x_hat1,x[i]))`.

If you want to use an implicit for loop, as in your second case, you simply need to restructure your statement.

The reference to i should come **before** the implicit loop:

`Distance.extend(hamming_distance(x_hat1,x[i]) for i in range(1, 6))`

Any of these options will work, it's up to you which you would prefer. (Personally the implicit loop is my favorite. It's a one-liner, not to mention much more pythonic than the straight for loop.)

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

More info on `list.extend` vs. the `list.append` functions in python (as that was your main confusion):

### Append:

Appends a single object to the end of a list

Examples:

```
 >>myList = [1,2,3]
 >>myList.append(4)
 >>myList
 [1,2,3,4]
```

**BUT** should not be used to add a whole list of elements

```
 >>myList = [1,2,3]
 >>myList.append([4,5,6])
 >>myList
 [1,2,3,[4,5,6]]
```

More info/examples:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_append.htm

### Extend:

Extends a list by using `list.append` on each element of the passed list

Examples:

```
 >>myList = [1,2,3]
 >>myList.extend(4)
 >>myList
 [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

**BUT** throws an error if used on a single element

```
 >>myList = [1,2,3]
 >>myList.extend(4)
 Type Error: 'int' object is not iterable
```

To extend a single element requires you to make a 1-item list: `myList.extend([4])`

More info/examples:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_extend.htm

**More on the differences:**
[append vs. extend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/python-append-vs-extend)